# Catplot with Seaborn, side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using this code below to plot a catplot with Seaborn. Its working ok.

```
sns.catplot(data=df_gol,
            x='MODALIDADE_DO_VOO',
            y='VALOR',row='DESTINO',
            kind='box',height=3, aspect=1,
            color='red')
```

But I am getting each box-plot stacked.

[image: Box-plot]

I'd like to plot it side by side. How can I do that?

My DF (df_gol) has these values:

```
Column DESTINO - ['JPA', 'FOR', 'SSA', 'AJU']
Column MODALIDADE_DO_VOO - ['Direto', '1 parada']
Columns VALOR is float type
```

I've been looking for some examples but I didn't understand how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [`col=` keyword](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot) instead of the `row=` to organize your subplots in columns. You can adjust the number of plots per row by using the `col_wrap=` argument.

```
sns.catplot(data=df_gol,
            x='MODALIDADE_DO_VOO',
            y='VALOR',col='DESTINO',       # <--- replaced row= by col=
            kind='box',height=3, aspect=1,
            color='red')
```